# how to make setInterval Wait until The function execute?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

i have a *setInterval* that execute a function every 100 ms

the problem is the setInterval does not wait until the function completely execute

here is the code :

```
    function Main(){


function AnyFunction(){ 


setTimeout(function(){

   console.log('Anything');


 },2000)



} 


setInterval(AnyFunction,100)  ; 


   }


Main();
```

what happens exactly in the function execute and how can i make setInterval Wait until The function execute ?

Comment: You could remove the setInterval and put a setTimeout inside the function

Comment: You mean wait until which function executes? @Seventh

Comment: @Nguyễn Việt Đức     AnyFunction()

Answer (score 0):

```
const anyFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}

const cycleAsync = (fn, time) => {
  const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    fn()
      .then(() => {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        cycle(fn, time);
      });
  }, time);
}


cycleAsync(anyFunction, 200);
```