# Can we make set Interval to wait until its function inside it is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an animation (Although I have not given exact code but an example of what I want to do) like I want that set Interval to wait until its inner function is completely executed then run itself again. There are many similar questions like [how to make setInterval Wait until The function executes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354272/how-to-make-setinterval-wait-until-the-function-execute)
(you are thinking of this question sounds similar to this question but this question's answer is not elaborating what's going on) and [Wait until setInterval() is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055530/wait-until-setinterval-is-done)
 but these questions are not giving my answer.
Can anyone tell me is it possible to do this? (if possible) then how?

```js
setInterval(()=>{
 setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log("hel1o")
 },3000)
},1000)
```

Comment: `function foo() { /* ... */ setTimeout(foo, 4000); } setTimeout(foo, 1000);`

Comment: @Andreas can you elaborate this please

Comment: There's only one function, and one `setTimeout()` call (the second is optional). You should be able to figure out how it works with a little research.

Comment: he's defining the function in the first line and he uses it inside the settimeout function in the second line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion and promises to do this. First wrap the code that you plan to execute in a function that returns a promise. Then create a recursive function that calls itself once the action is complete.

```js
const action = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("Action init")
  return setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Action completed")
    resolve();
  },3000)
})

const actionRecursion = () => {
  action().then(() => {
    setTimeout(actionRecursion, 1000)
  })
}

actionRecursion();
```

Comment: if this question seems useful you can upvote this

Comment: I looked at the question @ShayanKanwal and I couldn't run the code because my browser hanged everytime I tried. Using too many SVG elements can cause such lags, you should either use Canvas or even html img elements (convert the bee images to PNG).

Comment: Also you can automate most of your code, say `const allBees = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='corr-p']")`, which will store all bees in an array then you can run a loop to execute the timeouts like `allBees.forEach((bee,i) => { setTimeout(() => { /* code /*  }, (1500+1000*i)) })`

Comment: The comment section is not meant to be a discussion platform to get answers for other questions.

Comment: @Akshay Brother thanks a lot for this answer and can you please manipulate my code So it will better for me to understand this I am bothering with this for 3 days and didn't get that how to fix that everyone is giving suggestions not giving me the sample of code how to fix that. Can you please do this by manipulating my code I will be grateful to you.